# Include a quotation at the beginning of the references if I am using a bibtext file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, epigraphs

I have a bibtex file (library.bib) which looks like

```
Automatically generated by Mendeley Desktop 1.19.4 
Any changes to this file will be lost if it is regenerated by Mendeley.
BibTeX export options can be customized via Options -> BibTeX in Mendeley Desktop


@article{Article,
author = {Author,A}}
```

etc. This file is invoked from the main file with: `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`
And the result is something like:

```
 References 
 [1] Article, Author, Journal (2019) etc
```

Now, I would like to add a quote at the beginning of the References, right before the first reference appear; that is, I want something like:

```
  References 
                 Funny sentence
                 Author of funny sentence

 [1] Article, Author, Journal (2019) etc
```

At the beginning of chapters I do this by simply adding

```
\epigraph{\textit{funny sentence}}{author}.
```

But this seems impossible in the references with a bibtex file. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Did you try using `biblatex`,  redefining  the bibliography heading?

Comment: With `biblatex`, you could use the `prenote=...` option to `printbibliography`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably easiest to inject code for an epigraph into the bibliography heading definition similar to what [the `epigraph` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/epigraph/epigraph.pdf) suggests for `thebibliography` in section 2.5.

The heading definition below is based on `bibintoc` for `book`/`report` (cf. [`biblatex.def`, ll. 1911-1914 in v3.16](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L1911-L1914))

```
\documentclass[british]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
% based on 'bibintoc' for book/report
\defbibheading{bibintocWithEpigraph}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  \@mkboth{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}%
  \csuse{bibepi}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\bibepi}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
\epigraph{\textit{funny sentence}}{author}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\renewcommand*{\bibepi}{\epigraph{\textit{funny sentence}}{author}}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintocWithEpigraph]
\end{document}
```

[image: Epigraph for bibliography.]

---

An alternative approach that does not need to redefine any bibliography headings uses `\printbibheading` and `\printbibliography[heading=none]`:

```
\documentclass[british]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
\epigraph{\textit{funny sentence}}{author}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\epigraph{\textit{funny sentence}}{author}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```